# Burn - MsiPackage and Impersonation

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.7

I have an msi that allows the user to conditionally launch the installed application. The msi was created with Wix and includes the following xml statement:

```
<CustomAction Id='LaunchApplication' FileKey='foo.exe' ExeCommand='' Return="asyncNoWait" Impersonate="yes" />
```

The msi runs elevated, but the Impersonate option guarantees that the application is launched as the installing user.

The msi is included in my Burn package using the following statement:

```
<MsiPackage Id="FooMsi" SourceFile="$(var.Installer.TargetPath)" DisplayInternalUI="yes" Vital="yes" Permanent="no" />
```

However, Burn is elevated before the msi runs and therefore runs the application as Administrator.

Is there an impersonation option for Burn or do I have to launch the application from Burn instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burn launches per-machine packages from an elevated helper process so MSI impersonates the elevated user. There's no way to tell MSI to impersonate another user and/or different permissions. You can use the LaunchTarget attribute of the [WixStandardBootstrapperApplication element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/bal/wixstandardbootstrapperapplication.html) to launch a process from the unelevated Burn process.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'm using a custom/managed bootstrapper, so I assume I can use the LauchTarget variable instead?

Comment: LaunchTarget is a feature of WixStdBA. Since you're using a custom BA, you need to handle the UI and process launch in your own code.